# Null check in map gets null pointer exception

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, hashmap

I am trying to use a Java `HashMap`. Using `map.get("A")` to get a value for a key from the map resulted in a `NullPointerException`. Then I used `if(map.get("A"))` to avoid a `NullPointerException` being thrown, but it gets thrown anyway.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please show a complete code example. In particular, you need to include declarations for any relevant variables. Also be sure that the provided code accurately illustrates the issue you are asking about and doesn't introduce unrelated errors.

Answer (score 5):

I have answering my own question. I have used to check

```
         if(map.containsKey("A"))
                 String b =  map.get("A")
```

rather than

```
    if(map.get("A") != null)
            map.get("A")
```

It will help me to avoid null pointer exception

Answer (score 2):

Well, you probably didn't instantiate the `map` object itself.

Try this before accessing the `map`:

```
Map map = new HashMap();
```

And later:

```
map.put("A", "someValue");
if(map.get("A") != null){/*your code here*/}
```

Comment: Note that the `if` statement will only compile if the OP has `Map<String, Boolean> map`.

Comment: `if(map.get("A"))` will cause a compiler error. This isn't C++ or Python.

Comment: This will not work if we doesn't put map.put("A", "someValue");and try if(map.get("A") != null)

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible problems:

1. `map` itself is `null` because you never initialized it.
2. `map` is declared as `Map<String, Boolean> map`. If this is the case, then your `if` statement doesn't do what you think it does. It actually gets the `Boolean` object from the map and tries to unbox it to a primitive `bool`. If there is no value with the key `"A"`, then you will get a `NullPointerException`. The way to fix this is to change your `if` statement:

   ```
   Boolean b = map.get("A");
   if (b != null && b)
       ...
   ```

   Note that you have to explicitly compare with `null`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all check whether the map is null or not by

`map != null`

Then check map contains that key by,

`map.containsKey("A")`

Totally you can check as follows,

```
if(map!=null && map.containsKey("A")){
   if(map.get("A") != null){
       System.out.println(map.get("A"));
       \\ value corresponding to key A
   }
}
```

Comment: What if the the map is null in the First case, map.containsKey() will throw a null pointer!!!